# Count the number of spaces of the current line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

How can I count the number of spaces of the current line in a textarea

```
asdf
   asdf
asdf
```

If my cursor is current on line 2 then the result should be: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ta = document.getElementById('ta'); //set your textarea's id
    ta.onclick = function (e) {
        var lineNo = ta.value.substr(0, ta.selectionStart).split(/\r?\n|\r/).length,
            lineText = ta.value.split(/\r?\n|\r/)[lineNo - 1],
            numOfSpaces = lineText.split(/\s/).length - 1;
        console.log(lineNo, lineText, numOfSpaces);
    }
}
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/tfXN2/).

***NOTE:*** `textarea.selectionStart` does not work in some browsers. For a cross-browser support see **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263796/112731)**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string value of the textarea and then:

```
var textString = //pull data from textarea
var textArray = textString.split("\n");
for(var i=0; i<textArray.length; i++) {
    var count = textArray[i].match(/ /g); //regex to get any number of spaces 
    alert(count.length);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2qfHn/

Comment: Why not be constructive instead of down voting?

Comment: OP needs more granular solution , wants to know based on cursor posiiton. ALso your loop is checking the same `textArray[0]` each time

Comment: You'll need to get cursor position and then do the loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891444/how-can-i-get-cursor-position-in-a-textarea

Comment: @RayCheng Exactly. I am just showing that you can get data for each line. You would find the cursor line and pass that into `var count = textArray[i].match(/ /g);` instead of looping.

Comment: @charlietfl Fixed the typo as you posted that. :P

Comment: @jimjimmy1995, but that's only half of the story. He still need to find the location of the cursor. This one works better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea

Comment: @RayCheng Possibly more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153995/find-value-of-current-line-of-a-textarea-using-javascript